# How to properly restore Javascript context in v8?

Tags: javascript, v8

I want to do the following:

- execute a Javascript file with v8
- open a REPL which evaluates code in the exact same context as the code

Any variables or functions defined in the code file, for instance, should be available in the REPL.  (I'll note this used to work many v8 versions ago, but I can't figure out how to get it working in current v8 (node 0.12 == v8 3.28.73).)

I use a simple class JSInterpreter which has an isolate and a persistent context object as member vars.  They gets set up when the class is initialized, and bindings also happen at that time.

When it's time to interpret some code, I call this method:

```
Str JSInterpreter::InterpretJS (const Str &js)
{ v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope (isolate_);
  v8::HandleScope handle_scope (isolate_);

  //  Restore the context established at init time;
  //  Have to make local version of persistent handle
  v8::Local <v8::Context> context =
    v8::Local <v8::Context>::New (isolate_, context_);
  Context::Scope context_scope (context);

  Handle <String> source = String::NewFromUtf8 (isolate_, js . utf8 ());
  Handle <Script> script = Script::Compile (source);
  Handle <Value> result = script -> Run ();
```

I want to call this method over & over again, and each time, I want the context to contain any accumulated state from earlier calls.  So if the code file contains (only) `var x = 5;` at the REPL I should be able to type `> x` and see the result `5`.

But the actual result is `x is not defined`.

Comment: Hi, I know this is from long ago, but I am currently looking for ways to import and export v8 contexts, can you maybe share some examples of how this is used?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this code actually does work as expected.  The problem was that I was using browserify before running the code, and the code (e.g. `var x = 5;`) was getting wrapped into a function scope.